# SQL (MariaDB) join 3 tables and pivot

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb, pivot

I have 3 MySQL (MariaDB) tables:

Students:

| student_id | name | result_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Badui | 31 |
| 2 | Tama | 32 |
| 3 | Rombeng | 33 |

Subject:

| subject_id | points | result_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | 31 |
| 2 | 90 | 31 |
| 3 | 90 | 31 |
| 1 | 84 | 32 |
| 2 | 85 | 32 |
| 3 | 86 | 32 |
| 1 | 87 | 33 |
| 2 | 89 | 33 |
| 3 | 88 | 33 |

Average_Score:

| AS_id | average_score | result_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | 31 |
| 2 | 85 | 32 |
| 3 | 88 | 33 |

**Desired Table**:

| name | 1 | 2 | 3 | average_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Badui | 90 | 90 | 90 | 90 |
| Rombeng | 87 | 89 | 88 | 88 |
| Tama | 84 | 85 | 86 | 85 |

I need to have this view by using join and pivot, but I have no idea in combining the join and pivot altogether. This is my sql of JOIN

```
SELECT 
  name, subject_id, points, average_score 
FROM 
  Students as stud
JOIN 
  Average_Score as avr  
ON  
  stud.result_id = avr.result_id
JOIN
  Subject as subj
ON
  avr.result_id = subj.result_id
ORDER BY name
```

**and here is the result of the JOIN sql**

| name | subject_id | points | average_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Badui | 1 | 90 | 90 |
| Badui | 2 | 90 | 90 |
| Badui | 3 | 90 | 90 |
| Rombeng | 1 | 87 | 88 |
| Rombeng | 2 | 89 | 88 |
| Rombeng | 3 | 88 | 88 |
| Tama | 1 | 84 | 85 |
| Tama | 2 | 85 | 85 |
| Tama | 3 | 86 | 85 |

Is there any efficient way to modify my sql to match the pivot table to get the desired view?

I need some helps to have the correct query, please.
Thank you.

Comment: Open-ended pivot operations (those producing a data-dependent number of columns) are absurdly hard to do in MariaDB / MySQL.  Many production shops use client code (in C#, python, nodejs, whatever) to pull data from the RDBMS and format it into rows and columns.

Comment: @O.Jones, Can you reference another SQL product that can generate data-dependent columns without it being absurdly hard? I know about `PIVOT` in Microsoft SQL Server and `crosstab` in PostgreSQL. Are these so much easier? I'm sincerely curious if you know of a better solution.

Comment: What if you have more than just 3 `subject_id` in the future? Imagine this code is part of an application, does it mean that you have to keep on editing the query everytime there's a new `subject_id`?

Comment: You can use a prepared statement if you don't know how many subject ids you have. Though I wouldn't use that tool unless I really needed that. If you're in need of such thing for one of your problems, please share your question and I'll be happy to help. @FanoFN

Comment: It's a question for the OP @lemon ; there have been too many questions similar to this whereby the first requirement seems to be _"just this conditions"_ but after a while they came back with the same goal only with _"how can it be dynamic?"_ . I am actually quite familiar with prepared statements so I agree that it's one of the possible solution.

Comment: It just happened today to have solved a dynamic pivoting problem, can't agree more with your comment. @FanoFN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following query:

```
SELECT stud.name,
       MAX(IF(subj.subject_id=1, subj.points, NULL)) AS `1`,
       MAX(IF(subj.subject_id=2, subj.points, NULL)) AS `2`,
       MAX(IF(subj.subject_id=3, subj.points, NULL)) AS `3`,
       ROUND(AVG(subj.points))                       AS `average_score`
FROM       Students stud
INNER JOIN Subject  subj
        ON stud.result_id = subj.result_id
GROUP BY stud.name
```

The idea behind this solution is to join the tables *Students* and *Subject* on the `result_id` field, then get a column for each `points` corresponding to the related `subject_id` and aggregate with the MAX function to remove the NULL values. Eventually, instead of joining with the *Average_Points* table, you can just compute right away from the data you have in the *Subject* table.

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6nSiJCWWAfKZjnh9y48Umh/0).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works without any errors. About the Average_Score table, YES, you are right! It is way more efficient by computing it from the Subject table instead of joining all of them.

Again, thank you so much for the help!